# Trouble with sed expression using unicode range in new environment

Tags: linux, bash, sed, unicode, expression

I have the following `sed` range replacement expression in a `bash` clean script I wrote years ago that works (or at least never gave an error) in the old environment but fails (with an error) in the new and I can't determine why the range is invalid between the old and new environments.

The intent of the expression is to remove unwanted unicode or control characters from TSV files used to import data into our database.

The expression example in a one liner:

```
sed -e 's,[\x00\x01-\x08\x0a-\x1f\x7f]\+,,g' file.tsv
```

- The old environment: Ubuntu v16.04, Bash v4.3.46, GNU Sed v4.2.2
- The new environment: Ubuntu v20.04, Bash v5.0.17, GNU Sed v4.7

Error in new environment only (no error in old):

```
/usr/bin/sed: -e expression #1, char 35: Invalid range end
```

I tried running the expression on https://www.jdoodle.com/test-bash-shell-script-online and selecting the bash v5.0.011 which is using sed v4.7 and it does NOT produce the error, so perhaps it is NOT a version issue with sed or bash.

I can't recall exactly how I composed the character range used or why it appears there are two ranges (two -) but I feel I knew it enough to compose it many years ago effectively. Now I am trying to remember and diagnose this while migrating to a new docker container environment where the script runs.

**Questions:**

Does anything stand out as to why this would fail in one environment but not the other?

Is it possible it is not with the versions of sed, etc but rather a setting I made in the old environment that this expression requires? If you have any ideas on that, I can check and test.

**Note:** I don't actually need specific content to test this, I can just run the example above without the 'file.tsv' or an empty file and it will produce the same error in the new environment.

Comment: Replace `sed` with `LANG=C sed`?

Comment: Just tried it, same error.

Comment: I get the same error on Red Hat 8 but not Red Hat 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

edit: tl;dr:

```
sed 's,[\x00\x01-\x08\x0a\x0b\x0c\x0d\x0e-\x1f\x7f]\+,,g' /dev/null
```

is a workaround for this. Something's broken at the intersection of locale processing and ranges, if you shut off locale processing entirely with `LC_ALL=C` that part's fine but you don't get your unicode goodness, trying to get around whatever in the range-vetting code is broken got me to that one that works.

How I got there:

---

I tried it and didn't get that and then I looked for mistakes. I'd done `\x10` 'cause hex in my head.

```
$ LC_ALL=en_US.UTF8 sed 's,[\x00\x01-\x08\x10-\x1f\x7f]\+,,g' /dev/null
$ LC_ALL=en_US.UTF8 sed 's,[\x00\x01-\x08\x0a-\x1f\x7f]\+,,g' /dev/null
sed: -e expression #1, char 35: Invalid range end
$ LC_ALL=C sed 's,[\x00\x01-\x08\x0a-\x1f\x7f]\+,,g' /dev/null
$
```

This is some weird bug in locale processing. Running with `LC_ALL=C` makes it work for me.

Also, playing with the ranges, specifying `\x7f` separately works around it too, without needing to switch locales.

```
$ sed 's,[\x00\x01-\x08\x0a-\x7e\x7f]\+,,g' /dev/null
$
```

> I tried running the expression on https://www.jdoodle.com/test-bash-shell-script-online and selecting the bash v5.0.011 which is using sed v4.7 and it does NOT produce the error, so perhaps it is NOT a version issue with sed or bash.

When I add `LC_ALL=en_US.UTF8` at the front of the command it does pop that error there, though.

Comment: Adding LC_ALL=C does fix this expression's error! Yay!! Unfortunately, it now causes another expression (it is a multiple expression sed line in the script) to fail. This `-e 'y,０-９ａ-ｚＡ-Ｚ–－一（）【】,0-9a-zA-Z---()[],'` throws `/usr/bin/sed: -e expression #1, char 62: strings for 'y' command are different lengths` when using `LC_ALL=C` but not when using `LC_ALL=en_US.UTF8`. Hmm, thoughts?

Comment: Try breaking the `\x7f` out separately, `[whatever-\x7e\x7f]`.

Comment: I am trying to wrap head around how this changes the intended to result if I change the original to `'s,[\x00\x01-\x08\x0a-\x7e\x7f]\+,,g'` per your example above. What gets missed in your version that was found in my original? It is not clicking when you say break it out separately. Do you mean have a second expression to catch whatever is missed between the two expressions? I am a little rusty at reading these hex codes as ranges to know what it interprets as from my original.

Comment: See my edit at the top of the answer, this is a corner-case bug at the intersection of locale and codepoint-range processing. Away from my main system for a while so I don't have source+tools handy to shoot it, I had a hard time imagining the ranges themselves mattered too so it took a while to get an exact match for the sets you're after.

Comment: Ah - ok. I will test that too but in the meantime, is this what you meant before by breaking it out separately where I've done a separate replace expression just for the one hex code you removed? `sed -e 's,[\x00\x01-\x08\x0a-\x7e\x7f]\+,,g' -e 's,\x1f\+,,g'` ... is that equivalent to my original and your modified version at the top of your post?